# Extrair expressoes recorrentes em um objeto contendo pequenos textos em R

Tags: r

**CONTEXTO***

Estou trabalhando com um conjunto de textos, e estou procurando um subconjunto de textos que falem sobre "Conselhos de Políticas Públicas".

Quando um texto fala de conselhos de políticas públicas, pode conter este termo ou vários outros termos, tais como "conselho de saúde", "conselho de meio ambiente", etc.

Não tenho uma lista que me diga quais N termos se referem aos conselhos, então procurei as ocorrências da palavra "conselho" / "conselhos" + as 5 palavras seguintes. É exatamente aqui que meu problema começa:

**PROBLEMA**

Conselho é uma palavra ambígua que pode ter vários significados:

*"conselho ao garoto para parar"*

*"conselho da cidade da saúde"*

Tenho um objeto `termos_conselho` que contém todas as ocorrências atribuídas ao conselho + 5 palavras seguintes, e quero poder extrair as expressões recorrentes para poder saber manualmente a que se refere cada expressão.

Em código, isto pareceria assim:

```
termos_conselho<- c("conselhos e orientação da união. a", "conselho municipal de educação) do sistema,", "conselho municipal de educação e os", "conselhos de políticas e planos diretores", "conselhos de políticas públicas")

# Resultado: 
# conselhos
# conselho municipal de educação
# conselhos de políticas
```

Eu gostaria de algum tipo de `dinstinct` que limpe todas as palavras não recorrentes e devolva apenas os termos recorrentes.

Não sei por onde começar, portanto, qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda

Answer (score -2):

Não sei se entendi corretamente sua necessidade, mas segue uma sugestão:

Primeiro, converti seu vetor para uma tibble e o coloquei em uma coluna chamada "expressao":

```
termos_conselho <- tibble(expressao = c("conselhos e orientação da união. a", "conselho municipal de educação) do sistema,", "conselho municipal de educação e os", "conselhos de políticas e planos diretores", "conselhos de políticas públicas"))

# A tibble: 5 × 1
  expressao                                  
  <chr>                                      
1 conselhos e orientação da união. a         
2 conselho municipal de educação) do sistema,
3 conselho municipal de educação e os        
4 conselhos de políticas e planos diretores  
5 conselhos de políticas públicas
```

Em seguida, usando `str_extract()` coloquei o termo principal (em uma coluna chamada "raiz") e usando `str_remove()` aloquei o restante da frase (em uma coluna chamada "resto").

Em seguida, com a função `tabyl()` do pacote *janitor*, eu fiz o cruzamento para ter noção da associação entre os termos. A conversão em tibble ao final do código é apenas para deixar a leitura mais agradável.

```
termos_conselho %>%
  mutate(raiz = str_extract(string = expressao, 
                            pattern = "\\w+"),
         resto = str_remove(string = expressao, 
                            pattern = "\\w+")) %>% 
  tabyl(resto, raiz) %>% 
  as_tibble()



# A tibble: 5 × 3
  resto                                 conselho conselhos
  <chr>                                    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 " de políticas e planos diretores"           0         1
2 " de políticas públicas"                     0         1
3 " e orientação da união. a"                  0         1
4 " municipal de educação e os"                1         0
5 " municipal de educação) do sistema,"        1         0
>
```